WinUI, updating the main thread from two different parts of the application sometimes causes the application to freeze
Is there a pattern or technique to handle multiple calls to update the UI thread at the same time?
Let me explain my issue.
I have a WinUI (.net 7.0) application. I understand that the UI has a main thread and can only update the UI on that thread.
The UI is updated by users interacting with the applications. The UI is also updated by Kafka messages coming from the database. The Database will send a Kafka message stating that something has updated and in turn my application receives the message and updates the UI accordingly.
This all works great except occasionally if both the UI and Kafka try to update the UI thread at the same time the UI locks up.
For example. If updating data I call an Async method to save the data. The Async method has a callback to a method when the Save has completed. This in turn calls code on the UI thread to update the UI. If the DB sends a message at exactly the same time the Save Success code doesn't complete and leaves the UI in a hang state. The only way to recover is to kill the application.
So back to my original question:
Is there a pattern or technique to handle multiple calls to update the UI thread at the same time without it hanging.

What does at the same time mean here? If you're updating the UI from the main thread only, then updates from different sources are placed in the main thread's queue and they cannot happen simultaneously. I would recommend you to make sure that all updates are made from the main thread by explicitly passing the updating code to the DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue method (or any of its equivalents).

By the same time I mean that the user has updated the UI at the same time as Kafka update the UI. It happens very rarely and as you could imagine, difficult to test. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it some research.
